# TypeError: drCtx is null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and tried to do a simple function, but get this error while attempting to run:

> TypeError: drCtx is null

html:

```
<body onload="init()">
     <div style="min-width: 400px; display: inline-block;"></div>
     <canvas id="test" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
```

js:

```
var width, height;
var drCtx;
var charsize =15;
var chars = ["0","1"]
var charArray;
var c,r;
//Initialze canvas
function init(){
    var canvasElement = document.getElementById("test");
    drCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2D");

    width = canvasElement.width;
    height = canvasElement.height;

    c = parseInt(Math.ceil(width / charsize));
    r = parseInt(Math.ceil(height / charsize));
    charArray = new Array(c);
    for(var i=0; i<c;i++)
    {
        charArray[i] = new Array(r);
        for(var j =0; j<r;j++)
        {
            var rIndex = parseInt(randomIntFromInterval(0, chars.length-1));
            charArray[i][j] = chars[rIndex];
        }
    }
    console.log(charArray);
    renderDR();
}

function renderDR(){
    drCtx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    drCtx.beginPath();
    drCtx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    drCtx.fill();

    drCtx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"

    for(var i=0; i<c;i++)
    {
        for(var j =0; j<r;j++)
        {
            var x = i*charsize;
            var y = j*charsize;
            drCtx.fillText(charArray[i][j],x,y);
        }
    }
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

My init() fucntion doesn't have this problem and doesn't have return.
I don't know what went wrong, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `.getContext("2d")`, not `.getContext("2D")`. Turns out it’s a duplicate of [canvas.getContext('2D') returns null value](/q/18402577/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
.getContext("2D")
```

To:

```
.getContext("2d")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).